# How can I use LDAP as a login server for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and OpenLDAP

I want to use LDAP to manage my Linux users and groups but I don't know how. I searched Google and I found this: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/configure-ldap-client-on-ubuntu-16-04-debian-8.html. I'm not experienced in using LDAP but I want to learn it

My users are not shown in phpLDAPadmin

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First learn about LDAP and its basic schemas.  Then setup LDAP and add your users into LDAP.

Although dated the Linux Documentation Projects [LDAP HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/) covers the basics. LDAP hasn't really changed since this document was written.  I use the Zytrax [LDAP Book](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/) a lot.

OpenLDAP has changed a lot since then, and now stores most of its configuration in its database.

There are at least two packages that will populate an LDAP schema with your users and group.  Search the package manager for them.

Once you have your users in LDAP, you can configure NSS to provide user and group data from your LDAP server.

I configure a local user on each server in the standard files based system.  This is used to recover the system if I break LDAP.